# using xpath to retrieve one node from a xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I am trying to use xpath and strip xml for the first time I,

all I want to do is get the first node to show in the debug window here is my code.

```
' Create a WebRequest to the remote site
    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/datex/England/CurrentRoadworks/content.xml")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    ' Check if the response is OK (status code 200)
    If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then


        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
        Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

        document.LoadXml(contents)

        Dim node As System.Xml.XmlNode

        For Each node In document
            Debug.Print(node.SelectNodes("/situation").ToString())
        Next node

    Else

        Throw New Exception("Could not retrieve document from the URL, response code: " & response.StatusCode)

    End If
```

thanks for any help anyone can give!!!

here is the start of the xml doument

```
 <d2LogicalModel modelBaseVersion="1.0">
  <exchange>
    <supplierIdentification>
       <country>gb</country>
       <nationalIdentifier>NTCC</nationalIdentifier>
    </supplierIdentification>
  </exchange><payloadPublication xsi:type="SituationPublication" lang="en">   <publicationTime>2013-09-27T16:09:02+01:00</publicationTime>
```

gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call the select method on the document, not on the null node variable:

```vb
'This will not work because node is null (Nothing)
node.SelectNodes("/situation")

'This will work
document.SelectNodes("/situation")
```

The `SelectNodes` method returns a collection of nodes.  If all you want is the first one, call `SelectSingleNodes` instead, like this:

```vb
node = document.SelectSingleNode("/situation")
```

Then, rather than calling `ToString` on the node, call either `InnerXml`, `InnerText`, or `OuterXml`, depending on your preference, for instance:

```vb
node = document.SelectSingleNode("/situation")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    Debug.Print(node.InnerText)
Else
    Debug.Print("Node does not exist")
End If
```

However, after looking at the actual XML that you are trying to read, that will never find the node.  `/situation` will only find the node if it is the root element, but in the actual XML document, it is here: `/d2LogicalModel/payloadPublication/situation`.  However, there is also a second problem.  There is a default namespace defined on the root element: `xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0"`.  Therefore, you need to explicitly specify the namespace in your select, like this:

```vb
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("http://hatrafficinfo.dft.gov.uk/feeds/datex/England/CurrentRoadworks/content.xml")
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://datex2.eu/schema/1_0/1_0")
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/x:d2LogicalModel/x:payloadPublication/x:situation", nsmgr)
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    Debug.Print(node.InnerXml)
Else
    Debug.Print("Node does not exist")
End If
```

Note that there is no need to create the `HttpWebRequest` since the `XmlDocument` class is capable of loading directly from a URI.

Comment: getting error message Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: code looks like    Dim node As System.Xml.XmlNode

            node = document.SelectSingleNode("/Situation")
            Debug.Print(node.InnerText)

Comment: Is it failing on the `Debug.Print` line?  If so, that's because the `/Situation` element does not exist in the XML document.  Before printing the value, you should check `If node IsNot Nothing`.  That way, if the node doesn't exist, you won't cause an exception.  I updated my example to demonstrate how to do that.

Comment: yes that's where failing will look into the if Node why did I choose wuch a complex layout to learn on!!!!!!

Comment: is there an easy way of debug.print the document so I can double check the contents? the hard copy I have shows situation on the first line?

Comment: If you show some of the XML document, it may help.  A common problem, for instance, is that XPath won't find the node if the node is part of a particular XML namespace.  If so, you have to explicitly specify the namespace in your select.  If that's not the problem, is the `Situation` element at the root level of the document?  If not, use `//Situation`.

Comment: I see the whole document now think I had some parts collapsed when I printed the hard copy! here is a small part if I could pull the situation I would be on my way!!       the begining is to detailed to paste in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Try this with SelectSingleNode Function.

```
Dim xrn As XmlNode
Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
xd.LoadXml(xml)
xrn = xd.SelectSingleNode("//")

If Not IsNothing(xrn) Then
    mac = xrn.InnerText
End If
```

ozoid..

Comment: ozoid?  It looks more triangular, if anything... :)